# Skype URI with Microsoft Account

Tags: button, skype

I've got a Skype address created once Microsoft bought Skype, so I don't really have a "username", just an email address, connected to my account. How can I set up a button on my homepage where users can click it, and it will open up Skype if they have it and start a new chat with me?

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised it is not documented, but if you are using Skype with a Microsoft account and thus do not have a *Skype name*, here is what you can do:

First, sign into [web.skype.com](https://web.skype.com/en/). now click on your name on the top-left.

[image]

On the profile page that loads, you can see an ID below your name :
[image]

You can use this id instead of the skype name.

For example, if your id is `live:derp', you can use the following URI :

```
<a href="skype:live%3Aderp?chat"/>
```

note that you have to encode the ':' inside the id.